# File upload with text input field so user can enter file path too

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a form where the upload file looks like this:

[image]

I would like to make it look like this:

[image]

The reason for doing this is because the server already has the files. So I simply want to add the URL in the input field. However, the upload button is important too because we will need to upload files which aren't in the server yet.

How do we best go about this?

I currently have this code:

```
function wp_custom_attachment() {
    wp_nonce_field(plugin_basename(__FILE__), 'wp_custom_attachment_nonce');
    $html .= '<input type="file" id="wp_custom_attachment" name="wp_custom_attachment" value="" size="25" />';
    echo $html;
}
```

I tried a method like this but this ended up with a warning:

```
$html .= '<input type="text" value="" id="wp_custom_attachment" name="wp_custom_attachment" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById(\'file\').click();"><input id="file" type="file" name="img" onchange="ChangeText(this, \'wp_custom_attachment\');"/>';
```

Warning:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'url' in /path/content.php on line 42
```

Comment: Users must not write any path, simply because security concerns. IMHO you have to re-think your application logic.

Comment: This is for Admin Panel only. For convenience.

Comment: Do you trust *every* user who can login into your Admin Panel? Hope you don't.

Comment: The admin is just me and my colleague.

Comment: Why can't you upload the file and then generate a random hash behind the filename. In this way you will not run into problems of the filename being the same.

Comment: @TomGroot Thanks but that's a very different topic.

Comment: Can we get the code for `ChangeText`?

Comment: @TomGroot: I just edited out the question. Please ignore that. It was an attempt but I failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using a hidden input of `type='file'`, together with a `button` and an input of `type='text'`. To make the button active we add a trigger at the `onclick` of the button. `onchange` of the input `type='file'` we trigger a function `changeInput` to change the content of the input `type='text'`.

Which results in the following `html`:

```html
<input type="text" id="filename" name="filename"><button onclick="document.getElementById('file').click();">Open</button>
<input id="file" type="file" name="file" style="display: none;" onchange="changeInput()" />
<script>
function changeInput(){
  document.getElementById("filename").value = document.getElementById('file').value;
}
</script>
```

Be aware that this `html` puts the full path of the file in the `type='text'` input. When saving the new file, some parsing of the edited filename is required.

Comment: I resolved it already but this is better. Thank you so much. Accepted it :)